# Optimizar Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo dos funciones. Las dos hacen los mismo, pero como necesito que cuando cargue la página compruebe lo mismo que cuando le doy al botón, entonces la estoy replicando, una para cuando carga la página y otra cuando cambio yo la opción del select.

Hay alguna forma de hacerlo en una sola función?

```
window.onload=function() {
        var var1=document.getElementById('categoriaEle').value;
        $.get('add-producto/select_category/' + var1,function(data) {
            data.micat = data.micat || {};
                var tipoCat = data.micat.atributo;
                console.log(tipoCat);
                $("#tipo").val(tipoCat);
                if(tipoCat =="normal"){
                    $('#unico').show();
                    $('#variaciones').hide();
                    $('#teneis').show();
                }
                else{
                    $('#unico').hide();
                    $('#variaciones').show();
                    $('#teneis').hide();
                }
            $.each(data, function(fetch, subcategoria){
                
                $('#subcategoria').empty();
                for(i = 0; i < data.subcategoria.length; i++){
                    $('#subcategoria').append('<div class="form-check">\
                                                <input class="form-check-input subcategoriaSaca" type="radio" name="subcategoria" id="'+ data.subcategoria[i].id +'" value="'+ data.subcategoria[i].id +'">\
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="'+ data.subcategoria[i].id +'" style="color: #333;">\
                                                    '+ data.subcategoria[i].name +'\
                                                </label>\
                                               </div>');    
                }
            })
        })
    };

    function muestraMas(){
        var var1=document.getElementById('categoriaEle').value;
        $.get('add-producto/select_category/' + var1,function(data) {
            data.micat = data.micat || {};
                var tipoCat = data.micat.atributo;
                console.log(data);
                $("#tipo").val(tipoCat);
                if(tipoCat =="normal"){
                    $('#unico').show();
                    $('#variaciones').hide();
                    $('#teneis').show();
                }
                else{
                    $('#unico').hide();
                    $('#variaciones').show();
                    $('#teneis').hide();
                }
            $.each(data, function(fetch, subcategoria){
                
                $('#subcategoria').empty();
                for(i = 0; i < data.subcategoria.length; i++){
                    $('#subcategoria').append('<div class="form-check">\
                                                <input class="form-check-input subcategoriaSaca" type="radio" name="subcategoria" id="'+ data.subcategoria[i].id +'" value="'+ data.subcategoria[i].id +'">\
                                                <label class="form-check-label" for="'+ data.subcategoria[i].id +'" style="color: #333;">\
                                                    '+ data.subcategoria[i].name +'\
                                                </label>\
                                               </div>');    
                }
            })
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nada te impide asignar una función con nombre al `window.onload`. Siempre se suele ver una función anónima, pero no tiene por qué ser el caso, esto es perfectamente válido:

```
window.onload=muestraMas;

function muestraMas(){
//Código de la función aquí
}
```

Así que simplemente asígnale tu función y evitas repetir todo el código!
Lo único que tienes que tener en cuenta, es que cuando asignas la función quieres pasarle SOLO el handler (el nombre sin paréntesis), puesto que si no le estarás asignando no la función, si no lo que *devuelva* la función!

Comment: Perfecto! funciona a la perfección! gracias ;)